# Nested MasterPages MVC and WebForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nested, master-pages, webforms

I have a MVC Application "XYZ" and a Webform Application "demoApp", I have a master page in the MVC Application and a MasterPage in the WebForm App, I am trying to Nest the Masters through

MVC MasterPage : MVCApp.Master

```
<@Master Language="c#" MasterPageFile="~/Shared/Web.Master"
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage">
```

WebForm MasterPage

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.UI.MasterPage" %>
```

Also, I am using Areas to register my MVC App into the Web App.

The Functionality is that when I click a button on WebApp, I should be redirecting to the MVC Area which is working fine, it's just when I try to reference the MVC Page to a View like:

Welcome.Aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"  MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/MVCApp.Master" 
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Task>" %>
```

It says, file not found.